# Multiply large numbers by dividing them into 3 (Karatsuba with n/3 size)

Tags: algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I was solving some problems related to Karatsuba, when I came across a problem which says, how many multiplications would you need to multiply a large number divided into 3 smaller ones like this:

a = a0 a1 a2, for instance 102030 is a0=10 a1 = 20 a2=30, we do the same with another number.

How do I calculate the number of multiplications needed to multiply these 2 numbers?

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom3?

Comment: This works, thanks! Comment so I can mark as solved